# React jest tests not hitting coverage for api

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, react-testing-library

I have this api code called in some components.

```
const Api: IApi = {
  delete: (url: string): Promise<any> => {
    return axios.delete(url);
  },
  get: (url: string): Promise<any>  => {
    return axios.get(url)
  },
  post: (url: string, payload: IContact): Promise<any> => {
    return axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload))
  },
  put: (url: string, payload: IContact): Promise<any>  => {
    return axios.put(url, JSON.stringify(payload))
  },
}

export { Api }
```

All the components that use this api have been tested to 100% coverage except the API.
[image]

The files without coverage are interface (types) files.

The issue I am facing now is to try and test the API so it hits 100% coverage but all scenarios have failed. The get method only is covered even though all the other methods have been successfully mocked.

What is really going on here for the coverage to behave like this?

[image]

How can this coverage be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock the `axios` library, call the `delete`, `post` & `put` methods in your tests and make sure the mocks are correctly called.

Something like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { Api } from './users';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('Api', function() {
  it('should call delete correctly', () => {
    const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';

    Api.delete(url);

    expect(axios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
  });
});
```

Comment: you have saved me a lot of time having been at it for quite sometime, trying different ways of mocking. Even bring in the context provider. in the end for post & put I needed to stringify the payload in order for the tests to pass. 100% coverage achieved.